# laravel project not working on local server. why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, localserver

i want to run my laravel Project on my organization local server .. i tried this

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.100.8  --port=8000
```

i get this ip

`http://192.168.100.8:8000`

this ip work only on my PC not other PCs which are connected on same network

Comment: Other pc's will have a different ip address. You will have use a service like ngrok to share local url's . Laravel valet offers this feature with valet share.

Comment: You can use the xampp too and set a virtual host

Comment: check in your firewall that the port 8000 is opened